# jQuery keydown event, how not to return to recent state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, keydown

I'm trying to solve my problem since yesterday but with no results :(

What I want to do is to "addClass" to some element when I press arrow (up or down). It's working well

```
(...)

// search-input is a div with contenteditable="true"
// search-input as <input> doesn't work too
// search-list is a simple div

$('#search-input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 40 || e.keyCode == 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#search-list').children('p').eq(i).addClass('on');
        i++;
        $(this).stop(true);
    }
}

(...)
```

but when I release the arrow key, the addClass event is "removing" from choosen element. The point is that I want class "on" to be attached to this element even after I release the arrow key, not only when I'm holding the key pressed.

There is also similar problem with "i" variable that wont increment. Pressing the arrow key increments it once and decrements it right after releasing the key. In effect, though multiple key pressing, the "i" variable value is still the same.

What I want to do is a dropdown list with text input. Practically, something like on google.com. I mean, when I'm typing something in the google searchbar, there are few hints showed up and I can navigate through them by using arrow keys. I got almost all that functionality except the arrow key navigating.

I've tried also keyup and keypress events, but with no positive results.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code? I don't see a `removeClass`  anywhere. It doesn;t just magically disappear. Where did you define `i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code its working fine... check this jsfiddle

```
var i = 0;
$('#search-input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 40 || e.keyCode == 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('red');
        alert(i++)
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hjfgu4yc/

Comment: hmm.. you are right. so it has to be a problem with a rest of my code

Comment: Yes and like @putvande said without 'removeClass' it will not disappear magically ..try to figure that out and let us all know if you facing trouble :)

Comment: The problem was that I was loading content to #search-list with ajax after every key press. So the script worked fine, but right after that, the #search-list was refreshed so the element lost the "on" class.
Thanks for help! :)